# Can I make an application made as a C# Windows Application developed in Visual Studio 2012 as a portable application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, portability

I have made a Windows Form Application in C# using Visual Studio 2012. Can I publish this as a portable application to windows machines ?

P.S. portability here I am referring is working with any Windows( preferably windows 7 or 8 ) machine without installation and .net framework

Comment: I don't think you can become completely portable since you'll still need the .NET Framework installed. I understand that [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) can be included with the program which would make it more portable, but I haven't tried it or know how to.

Comment: @Default This, from what I understand, is exactly what .NET Native promises to provide: no need for .NET framework on the target machine.

Comment: @WimOmbelets it states that *The .NET Native Preview released today only targets Store apps but we're working on improving native compilation for all .NET apps.*. It would be great if they fixed that. Nice find!

Comment: So dont i want to have .net framework on the machine ?

Answer (score 2):

Yup.
All you need to do is sheep your `bin` folder. It has your executable and all dependencies.
No installation will be required.

Just bear in mind that in order to be really portable, you will need to make sure that your application does not modify registries or computer configurations.

(from wikipedia:)

> A portable application (portable app), sometimes also called
>   standalone, is a program designed to run on a compatible computer
>   without being installed in a way that modifies the computer's
>   configuration information.

Comment: You'd still have to install the .NET Framework, correct?

Comment: @Default That is correct. still, I think it is a reasonable to refer to an application as portable if this is the only prerequisite. It is not uncommon that you know that your users have this installed as part of their OS (this of course depends on the OS and required version of .NET)

Comment: @AviTurner So that means if there isnt .net framework on the machine first I have to install .net framewok ?

Comment: @user3218743 That is correct. To be honest, I can't see a way for you to avoid this. On the other hand it is very common for users to have it installed. For example [win 7 gets .Net 4 via Win Update](http://superuser.com/questions/298025/does-windows-7-have-net-4-installed-by-default)

Answer (score 0):

You can if you do not have any dependencies, e.g. you have only the .EXE. If you have some .dlls you can use ILMerge to merge them into one .EXE

Comment: Would that remove the dependency on the .NET framework?

Comment: Thank you. But dont I want .net framewrok then ?

Comment: If you want to write non-.NET-dependent applications I would suggest you to switch the language.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you understand under *portable*. Avi's answer certainly works, as does ILMerge, but there's also the *one file, no installation needed* approach to portability.

I tread carefully because I don't want to advertise any application or another, but apart from taking the entire /bin folder, I've played around with [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/) in the past and that seems to do a pretty decent job at virtualizing (and rendering portable) most applications as long as they aren't too large (or maybe have too many dependencies on what have you, not sure). Alternative tools may exist, I haven't researched any of them recently and neither do I prefer or affiliate myself with any of them.

Seems to work fine for your average app. I've tried to virtualize Visual Studio, that was fun. Big no-no. 
Who knows, it might suit your needs. It still doesn't take away the need for a .NET framework installed on the target machine though. As I mention in comment, that might be something for .NET Native (and, at time of writing, the future).

Comment: I am sorry I did not uniderstand that virtualizing Visual Studio part.

Comment: chances are that for very large applications, conversion/virtualization will fail. Will probably work fine for your own application.